# Can't explain why not redirecting after login using RedirectFromLogin

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, forms-authentication

I am using ASP.NET MVC, on my login action I am doing:

```
[AcceptVerbs("POST")]
public ActionResult Login(FormCollection form)
{
    User validatedUser = // tests username/pwd here.

    FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(
        validatedUser.ID.ToString(), rememberMe);

    if(String.IsNullOrEmpty(Request["ReturnUrl"]))
        string redirectUrl = Request["ReturnUrl"];

    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.QueryString["ReturnUrl"]))
        string redirectUrl = Request["ReturnUrl"];
}
```

My url looks like this when I am on the login page:

```
http://localhost:56112/user/login?ReturnUrl=/admin/settings
```

Does anything look wrong here?

My web.config:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
    <forms loginUrl="/user/login"
        protection="All"
        timeout="30"
        name="SomeCookie"
        requireSSL="false"
        slidingExpiration="true"
        defaultUrl="default.aspx" />
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would recommend you against using `RedirectFromLoginPage` method in an MVC application. It would be better to perform redirects using standard ASP.NET MVC techniques. You may use [SetAuthCookie](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/twk5762b.aspx) method:

```
public ActionResult Login(FormCollection form)
{
    // ...
    FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(validatedUser.ID.ToString(), rememberMe);
    // ...
    return Redirect(FormsAuthentication.DefaultUrl); // will read default url from web.config
}
```

Comment: why do you suggest against it? (curiuos)

Comment: Because the recommended way to perform a redirect in an ASP.NET MVC application is to return the proper ActionResult from the action. `RedirectFromLoginPage` is close to impossible to unit test.

Comment: the above solution works, but why even call FormsAuthentication.DefaultUrl. Why not just redirect to the controller and action directly from your code. "RedirectToAction" is a better solution.